# Number of days for delivery and number of orders delivered in two separate columns. Is there a way to get summary statistics about orders?

Tags: excel

I've had a bit of trouble explaining this so please bear with me. I'm also very new to using excel so if there's a simple fix, I apologize in advance!

I have two columns, one listing number of days starting from 0 and increasing consecutively. The other column has the number of orders delivered. The two correspond to each other. For example, I've typed out how it would look below. It would mean that there were 100 orders delivered in 1 day, 150 orders delivered in 2 days, 800 orders delivered in 3 days, etc.
[image]

Is there a way to get summary statistics (mean, median, mode, upper and lower quartiles) for the number of days it took for the average order to get delivered? The only way I can think of solving this is to manually punch in "1" 100 times, "2" 150 times, etc. into a new column and take median, mean, and upper & lower quartile from that, but that seems extremely inefficient. Would I use a pivot table for this? Thank you in advance!

I tried using the data analysis add-on and doing summary statistics that way, but it didn't work. It just gave me the mean, median, mode, and quartiles of each individual column. It would have given me 3 for median number of days for delivery and 300 for median number of orders.

Comment: Do you have Office 365? And what's an approximate upper bound on the total number of orders delivered? In your example it's 6700, though will it ever be much larger, for example more than a million?

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**

The mean is just

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A6,B2:B6)/SUM(B2:B6)
```

Mode is the value with highest frequency

```
=INDEX(A2:A6,MATCH(MAX(B2:B6),B2:B6,0))
```

The quartiles and median (or any other quantile by varying the value of p) from first principles following [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile)

```
=LET(p,0.25,
values,A2:A6,
freq,B2:B6,
N,SUM(freq),
h,(N+1)*p,
floorh,FLOOR(h,1),
ceilh,CEILING(h,1),
frac,h-floorh,
cusum,SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(values)),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=1,0,a+INDEX(freq,c-1)))),
xlower,XLOOKUP(floorh-1,cusum,values,,-1),
xupper,XLOOKUP(ceilh-1,cusum,values,,-1),
xlower+(xupper-xlower)*frac)
```

[image]

---

**Method 2**

If you don't like doing it this way, you can always expand the data like this:

```
=AVERAGE(XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(SUM(B2:B6),1,0),SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A6)),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=1,0,INDEX(B2:B6,c-1)+a))),A2:A6,,-1))

=MODE(XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(SUM(B2:B6),1,0),SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A6)),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=1,0,INDEX(B2:B6,c-1)+a))),A2:A6,,-1))

=QUARTILE.EXC(XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(SUM(B2:B6),1,0),SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A6)),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=1,0,INDEX(B2:B6,c-1)+a))),A2:A6,,-1),1)



=MEDIAN(XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(SUM(B2:B6),1,0),SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A6)),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=1,0,INDEX(B2:B6,c-1)+a))),A2:A6,,-1))
```

and

```
=QUARTILE.EXC(XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(SUM(B2:B6),1,0),SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A6)),LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=1,0,INDEX(B2:B6,c-1)+a))),A2:A6,,-1),3)
```