# How to calculate average etc from table containing frequences of values?

Tags: excel, average, frequency, median, mode

In an Excel table, one column contains grades from 4 to 10. Another column contains the number of each grade. How do I calculate the median, mode, and average of the grades?

I know I can calculate those by listing each grade and then using appropriate functions. I would like to know if there are functions in Excel which calculate these statistics from a table like this.

[image: Table]

I tried functions AVERAGE, MEDIAN and MODE.SNGL. I expected them not to work and was right.

Comment: Similar question answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75280446/number-of-days-for-delivery-and-number-of-orders-delivered-in-two-separate-colum

Comment: You can do this with one formula: `=LET(_data,A2:B8,
_numero,INDEX(_data,,1),
_oppilaita,INDEX(_data,,2),
_array,XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(SUM(_oppilaita)),SCAN(0,_oppilaita,LAMBDA(x,y,x+y)),_numero,,1),
_a,AVERAGE(_array),_b,MEDIAN(_array),_c,MODE.SNGL(_array),
VSTACK({"Average","Median","Mode"},HSTACK(_a,_b,_c)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is in `A2:B8` (excluding headers), generate this array:

```
=LET(
    ζ,A2:B8,
    ξ,TAKE(ζ,,-1),
    κ,SEQUENCE(ROWS(ξ)),
    INDEX(TAKE(ζ,,1),XMATCH(SEQUENCE(SUM(ξ)),MMULT(N(κ>=TOROW(κ)),ξ),1))
)
```

which you can then pass to your desired function(s).

Comment: Nice solution!, it works even when the frequency is zero, which is, in theory, a possible value. To improve performance, we can take advantage of `XMATCH` binary search since `lookup_array` (output of `MMULT`) is always in ascending order, therefore we could add `search_mode=2` input argument to `XMATCH` call, so it could be: `XMATCH(SEQUENCE(SUM(ξ)),MMULT(N(κ>=TOROW(κ)),ξ),1,2)`

Comment: @DavidLeal Good point re binary searching, thanks!